# Type properties in discriminated union types

Tags: typescript, union-types, discriminated-union, mapped-types

I want to create a discriminated union where all objects are of another type.

say i have a type

```
type PersonNames = 'john' | 'kate'
type Person = {
  name: PersonNames,
  favorites: unknown // can be any object
}
```

and i want to create a `PersonPreferences` type that is a union of `Person` objects such that only `PersonNames` is allowed for `name`...

```
type PersonPreferences = 
| {
   name: 'john'.
   favorites: {
     food: 'pizza'
   }
| {
   name: 'kate',
   favorites: {
     book: 'horror'
   }
```

How can this be accomplished?

I tried this but it allows for arbitrary names

```
type PersonPreferences = Person & (
| {
   name: 'john'.
   favorites: {
     food: 'pizza'
   }
| {
   name: 'jimmy',  // should error
   favorites: {
     book: 'science'
   }
)
```

Comment: Aside from the typos, what's wrong with your second code block? It is constructing a discriminated union of `Person` objects using only your specified names, which is what you've said you're trying to do. [TypeScript Playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOwHIEMC2FFQF4oByAK2QAtVioAfEga02AmIFgAoUSWBFVQlADenKGKiocEAFy8kaLLkQAaUeIBmmAG7J4ASxaJZAV1QNUyAO4CA9DagBjTAIBG0ZyCjIXpCA+CcAL6cnNzQcPKoMPAQ6ggQqA54gmpi9CIc4lkSUrJklNSqmdlimjr6hrIZJSXqyMgAJnlgegBerZjsxSXB3VC9Wemp2ZK4eUwsxEU1UGW6BnhVwzMu9Qx5FLrwul0zA+KBANxAA)

Comment: There's no native type-level `satisfies` operator so you'd have to write one yourself, maybe like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w2v7bw) shows. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer (unless I find a dupe target). If not, what am I missing?